# Concatenate multiple CSV files in a windows machine by running a shell command through python

Tags: python, windows, shell, awk

Objective: Concatenate multiple CSV files given some specific conditions.

- Conditions: Windows 10 machine + ANY shell command (e.g., `awk`) + Python <= 3.7.
- Disclaimer: I know that are plenty of ways of doing this which includes: using pandas dataframe concatenation; OR using python's `shutil`; OR using system command (e.g., `awk`) directly without python on a shell. But again, I want an answer that fits these exact above conditions.

Here is a shell command example (which works if I run directly on a shell) that I am currently trying to run

```
$ awk "(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)" "..\\results\\raw*.csv" > "..\\results\\consolidated.csv"
```

And this is how I run it through python's `subprocess`:

```py
src_files = os.path.join('..', 'results', 'raw*.csv')
dest_file = os.path.join('..', 'results', 'consolidated.csv')

result = subprocess.run('awk "(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)" "{}" > "{}"'.format(src_files, dest_file),
                        shell=True,
                        capture_output=True)
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```py
print(result.stderr)

b"awk: fatal: cannot open file `..\\results\\raw*.csv' for reading (No such file or directory)\n"
```

I should point out that if I run this python code on a Unix machine it works (if the quotes around the format `{}` are removed). The python code just not works on a Windows machine.

Thus, I believe this may have something to with properly escaping the command string because when I specify the name of some files, this command works. Still, I can't manage to find the proper way of escaping the `*` symbol and make all of this work.

PS: Generating the data for a working example

```py
for i in range(1, 4):
    pd.DataFrame([[i*1, i*2, i*3]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c']).to_csv(os.path.join('results', 'raw-{}.csv'.format(i)), index=False, sep=';')
```

PS2: Employed folder structure

```
|-- script_folder/
|   |-- consolidation_script.py
|-- results/
|   |-- raw-1.csv
|   |-- raw-2.csv
|   |-- raw-3.csv
```

Comment: Try using the [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#module-shlex) module to quote the arguments.

Comment: Hi @martineau, just tried the `shlex.quote()`, but it still did not work, same error. The `shlex.join()` seems promising, but it is only available in python 3.9 and I am restricted to python 3.7.

Comment: A dumb question from me, but why do you need awk to do that?  The command "type ..\results\raw*.csv > ..\results\consolidated.csv" doesn't do what you want?

Comment: The command you're trying to run is `'awk "(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)" "..\\results\\raw*.csv" > "..\\results\\consolidated.csv"'` which is too complicated for `subprocess.run()` — for example redirecting the output is done via the `stdout=None` keyword argument. I agree with @Ian that this would probably best be done completely with Python instead of using an external program like `awk`.

Comment: @IanMcGowan I do not necessarily need `awk`, it can be any any shell command. For instance, some people like to use `sed`. It is just that I am most used to use `awk` when I want to combine `.csv` files via shell command and keep a header.

Comment: Please post the full command line code that works outside of Python.

Comment: It's very easy to skip CSV headers using Python's included `csv` module (or even manually in most cases).

Comment: @IanMcGowan Sure, as I said in the question I can just concatenate dataframes using pandas, or use python's `shutil`. There are a plethora of ways to do this but the challenge here is do this given the conditions I am describing in the question.

Comment: @Parfait Added the shell command to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the `cwd` argument to change working directory after locating current script path. And yes, `os.path.dirname()` is called twice to get parent of current directory.

```py
import os, subprocess

# RETRIEVE CURRENT DIRECTORY OF SCRIPT
cd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

arglist = ["awk", "(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)", "raw*.csv", ">", "consolidated.csv"]

result = subprocess.run(arglist,
                        cwd = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(cd), 'results'),
                        shell=True,
                        capture_output=True)
```

Comment: This seems promising. I will try it as soon as I get back to my machine from work. Do you think this can still function with relative paths?

Comment: In a way this is a relative path solution as it works from the directory that script resides in. Only the subfolder, *results*, and .csv file names are hard-coded.

Comment: Hi Parfait, your solution worked perfectly. But, it requires a small adjustment here `cwd = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(cd), 'results')`. It should be `cwd = os.path.join(cd, 'results')`. Would you please edit your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Hmmm... as I mentioned you need to call `os.path.dirname()` twice. Is Python script in same level as `results` folder and not within a `script_folder` as you show above?

Comment: Oops, you are right. I was the one making a mistake because I was actually using a jupyter server that was being started one level above the notebook, and thus it did not require this second `dir_name` call. Anyway, your answer fits perfectly with the situation I described in the question. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great to hear and happy to help! Happy coding!